# Docker compose on Google container engine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup my project with `docker-compose up -d` on google container engine. This resulted in an error message

> ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater.

I proceeded to upgrade docker-engine with `sudo apt-get upgrade docker-engine`, which lead to a conflict between client API version and server API version as witnessed by `docker version` :

> Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.21)

This I managed to deal with by `DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.21 docker info`. The result is

```
Containers: 0
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 0
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
Volume: 
Network: 
Swarm: 
NodeID: 
Is Manager: false
Node Address: 
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) (containerized)
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.664 GiB
Name: cs-6896-devshell-vm-eb4ae861-f469-41bb-a126-c0f68ecdb2b3-10e
ID: X75G:3CR6:QA5D:PFO3:Y2ZM:FEI3:LDLW:TM7B:2JGT:HLXF:67Q5:K76D
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: No cpuset support
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
```

However, I still get the same error of docker engine being too old. `sudo apt-get upgrade docker-engine` does not help.

How can I update docker-engine, or get to run `docker-compose` otherwise?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

You might not be able to use docker-compose on Kubernetes but [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845715/can-kubernetes-be-used-like-docker-compose) mentions some alternatives.